# How to make a for-loop optional

Tags: r, for-loop, conditional-statements

I want to run a script that evaluates an expression depending on a boolean variable either within a for-loop or just once.

The code should look something like this:

```r
forCond <- function(..., cond, expr) ifelse(cond, for(...) expr, expr)
```

But I'm not exactly sure how the three dots ellipsis works. My idea was to use it to pass something like `i in vec` to the for-function. And the argument(s) passed by `...` are supposed to be ignored if `cond` is `FALSE`.

I want my code

```r
forCond(i in vec, cond, expr)
```

to be equivalent to

```r
if (cond) {
  for(i in vec) 
    expr
} else {
  expr
}
```

How do I do this elegantly? Or is there a better method to do this, namely evaluating an expression multiple times (with different counting variables), maybe using something like lapply?

I'll give an example:

```r
cond <- TRUE
vec <- 1:10
i <- 1 # Initialize i in case cond is FALSE
forCond(i in vec, cond,
  {
    print(i)
    print(2 * i)
  })
```

This is supposed to be the same as

```r
for(i in vec) {
  print(i)
  print(2 * i)
}
```

And in case `cond` is `FALSE`, I want something like

```r
i <- 1
print(i)
print(2 * i)
```

Comment: Can you include the actual working code which you want to optimize?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot. I want to train a model depending on some parameters of a data set. For runtime purposes, I want to exclude one parameter that has many different values. However, I don't want to rewrite the entire script every time I want to fix that parameter (that is to make a spot check using a random value that parameter can take on).

Comment: Voting to close as too broad, because you can't show the actual code you want to optimize.

Comment: I suspect you might be better off exploring a construct along the lines of `for (i in vec) {expr; if (cond) break}`.

Comment: @MikkoMarttila thank you, that is what I was looking for.

Comment: You cannot have a call like `forCond(i in vec, cond,
  {
    print(i);
    print(2 * i)
  })` in R. The parser only deals correctly with `in` if it is actually preceded by `for`.

Comment: Also, `ifelse` and `if`/`else` are fundamentally different. Never try to use `ifelse` like you show in the beginning.